# Access web service in window phone 8

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to access web service in window phone. But I cannot find any particular method to access this web service. I'm just creating web service method below

```
 [WebMethod]
        public string ListCategory(int Id, string JsonXml)
        {
            tidybeans.DAL.Category category = new tidybeans.DAL.Category();
            if (JsonXml.ToLower() == ("Json").ToLower())
                return CreateJsonParameters(category.GetAllDS(Id));
            else if (JsonXml.ToLower() == ("xml").ToLower())
                return ConvertDatatableToXML(category.GetAllDS(Id));
            else
                return "Please enter the type";
        }
```

Now I'm not able to find any method to consume web service in window phone 8 application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the web service as a service reference to your project. instantiate its soap client and use it to call the web service method

Windows phone uses asynchronous operations

Example:

```
ExampleService.MyWebServiceSoapClient client = new ExampleService.MyWebServiceSoapClient();
```

(in your method)

```
client.ListCategoryCompleted += client_ListCategoryCompleted;
client.ListCategoryAsync(Id,JsonXml);
```

(the listcategorycompleted method)

```
void client_ListCategoryCompleted(object sender, ExampleService.ListCategoryCompletedEventArgs e)
{
//you can hanlde the result here
//txtDisplay.Text = e.Result;
}
```

ExampleService is the name for the service reference

Comment: i get this Exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' was thrown.

Comment: Thnks Nyandika.It's my mistake to use wrong method to display